# React.ForwardRef loses infer type of generic type

Tags: reactjs, react-forwardref

I'm using React, and in this case the feature `React.forwardRef`.
The problem I'm having is that, after using the `React.forwardRef`, I lose the inferred type of a generic type `T` when using the component that is wrapped by `React.forwardRef`.

Let me explain with an example; take this code:

```
interface IUser {
    nickname: string;
}

interface IList<TRecord> {
    items: TRecord[];
    children: (item: TRecord) => React.ReactElement;
}

export const List = <TRecord extends unknown>(props: IList<TRecord>) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.items.map(x => <li>{props.children(x)}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
}

export const MyApp = () => {
    const items : IUser[] = [];
    return (
        <List items={items}>
            {item => <p>{item.nickname}</p>}
        </List>
    );
}
```

When I write `{item.nickname}` inside the `return` of `MyApp`, TypeScript can infer the type of `item` based on the props `items` passed to `<List>`.

[image]

Now, let me wrap `List` with `React.forwardRef`, like so:

```
export const List = React.forwardRef(<TRecord extends unknown>(props: IList<TRecord>, ref: any) => {
    return (
        <ul>
            {props.items.map(x => <li>{props.children(x)}</li>)}
        </ul>
    );
});
```

Here's what TypeScript tells me:

[image]

As you can see, TypeScript cannot infer anymore the type of `item`. What I think is happening is that, using `React.forwardRef`, I'm losing the genericness passed via the props `items`.. But I have no idea how I could fix this.